# R - Creating for loop replacing negative values for random integers, and counting negative values

Tags: r

Create a for loop that replaces the negative values in a numeric matrix with a random integer between 1 and 10. At the same time, it counts the negative values and prints their number.

I tried doing this for the first part but it did not work.

Could anyone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take a look at this [ask]. You also should post your codehere you have tried so far so we can better understand what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
# sample data
mat = matrix(data = sample(-10:10, size=40, replace = T), nrow = 5)
print(mat)

# count of negative values
print(length(mat[mat < 1]))

# replace negative by random int
mat[mat < 1] = sample(1:10, size=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
print(sum(mat<0))
replace(mat,mat<0,sample(1:10,sum(mat<0),replace = TRUE))
```

or nested `for` loop

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(mat)) {
    if (mat[i,j]<0) {
      mat[i,j] <- sample(1:10,1)
    }
  }
}
```

**Example**

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(15),3,5)
> mat
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] -0.6264538  1.5952808 0.4874291 -0.3053884 -0.6212406
[2,]  0.1836433  0.3295078 0.7383247  1.5117812 -2.2146999
[3,] -0.8356286 -0.8204684 0.5757814  0.3898432  1.1249309

> print(sum(mat<0))
[1] 6

> replace(mat,mat<0,sample(1:10,sum(mat<0),replace = TRUE))
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 10.0000000 1.5952808 0.4874291 4.0000000 3.000000
[2,]  0.1836433 0.3295078 0.7383247 1.5117812 6.000000
[3,]  9.0000000 1.0000000 0.5757814 0.3898432 1.124931
```